# Data queries and computation happen in MySQL server or Rails server?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, backend

I need to run a long backend job with long MySQL queries regularly, which will take several hours to complete. I set up  Delayed Job gem to schedule this job.

When this process is running:

- Will this job slow down my Rails front-end server (i.e., it will take much longer to response to a simple user's request)?
- Where heavy computation happens: in my Rails server, or in MySQL server?
- Will MySQL server be occupied by my scheduled job, and no one can access MySQL at the same time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is:  It depends

1. If your task is processor intensive it could slow down the rails server.  If you are concerned about the DJ workers impacting the front end box, move them to another box with access to a shared DB.  Your worker box needs the project setup but does not need to be the same box you are serving pages from.
2. This is completely dependent on how you wrote your task.  Typically a rails app does simple select / insert / update / delete.  the actual computation is done in rails.  But you can specify select statements that involve complex joins or take advantage of functions in the DB.  This can offload the computation of complex fields to the DB
3. This is dependent on the number of connections your DB is configured to accept.  Typically in a production level server, you wouldn't see an issue here from the size of your query.  But you should take into account how many active connections there are and how many are permitted.  Each rails instance counts as a connection, as well as each worker for DJ.

In each case the actual performance is going to depend on several factors.  How many connections are you creating, how much data are you transmitting between worker and DB.  Where are you doing the work.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben. Could you kindly advice on how I can setup another box which allows me to utilize Rails functions, get the same project setup, and access to shared database? I have my Rails app in Heroku. I am not sure if I can add a worker dynos and assign it to just backend jobs. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert with Heroku.  But i did find this article that may be of aid to you: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already setup delayed-job. But I am not sure if it creates another box, or just create a new thread running on Rails server. Please correct me if I am wrong, b/c I am a newb here.

Comment: Since you are running in heroku, the "other box" concept is mute i believe.  It is a cloud environment and you shouldn't need to worry about a dyno slowing you down.  But i am not an expert on heroku as I said.

Comment: I'm only familiar with my deployment environment (Joyent),  and there,  everything (web server, rails app and mysql) are on the same box.  Now if Heroku is set up in such a way that by default the mysql is on another box (don't know)  then the nice command is a little less relevant.  But my guess (just due to the complexity of doing it otherwise),  is that when they provision you an account,  your rails app and mysql ARE running on the same box,  and the nice command would be the simplest thing you could do to eliminate responsiveness issues when running your delayed job.

Comment: Thanks you, RadBrad. I think mySQL is in a separate box (and actually hosted by ClearDB).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben, for going extra miles to help.

Comment: If that's the case, then 'nice' still may help,  but you'd have to benchmark and verify.  However you kick off your delayed job,  stick 'nice -n 20' in front of the command,  that means you are asking to be as NICE as possible WRT not hogging CPU resources.  In this case you're only asking the delayed job on heroku to be nice to all the other jobs running on heruko.  The niceness wouldn't get shipped of to ClearDB.  It's worth a try though!

Answer (score 1):

If the rails server is on the same machine as the mysql server,  then there will be some impact.  But your OS, and MySQL together, are pretty capable of minimizing the effects without much other intervention by you. Depending how you're deployed,  you can always utilize the 'nice' command,  and lower the priority of the delayed job,  minimizing it's impact on your site's responsiveness.